# react - is styling with use of method is a good practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple React app and some of the components of this app require dynamic styling. Is it allowed to use method for there is some other recommended ways to do this? Everythings works fine, however I don't want to use some anti-pattern.

e.g.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
  block_style() {
   if (!!this.state.folder.image) {
     return {"backgroundImage": "url(" + this.state.folder.image + ")";
   } else {
     return {"backgroundColor": "orange"};
   }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.block_style.bind(this)()}>
        // ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with this approach that make them not a great choice.

The first is that you are binding the function in the `render()` function. The problem with this is when you `bind()`, it actually returns a new function. Since you are creating that in the `render()` function, every time it goes to render, it'll see that new function and always re-render, creating a lot of unnecessary renders. You should always bind in the `constructor()` or somewhere else that'll only happen once.

The second is simply that there is no need to `bind()` where you are using it. You only need to bind when you aren't calling it right away (like passing it to an event handler) where the context may be lost. If you are calling it right away, then you have the context and there is no need to bind.

The third is similar to the first. Even once you fix the `bind` issue, because the function returns a new object, you'll have a similar issue as the first. Since it will always be a new object (even if it contains the same data), it will trigger React to re-render every time, creating a lot of unnecessary renders.

Instead, a better approach is to update your `state` at the same time you are updating `state.folder` and create and store your styles:

```
someFuncWhereYouUpdateFolder() {
  const folder = getFolder();
  this.setState({
    folder,
    style: folder.image 
      ? { backgroundImage: `url(${folder.image})` } 
      : { backgroundColor: 'orange' }
  });
}
```

Then, you simply have to use that style in your render:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div style={ this.state.style }>
     { /* stuff */ }
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more about not creating objects in `render()` see articles like [this](https://medium.com/@jooj123/react-dos-and-don-ts-1177fb12351a) (#6 in particular) and [this](https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f).

Answer (score 0):

A pretty common practice with inline-styling is to create objects that you switch between depending on state.

```
this.state = {
  folderImage: null
}

render() {
  let folderImage = {};

  if (this.state.folderImage) {
    folderImage.background = `url($this.state.folderImage)`
  } else {
    folderImage.background = "orange"
  }

  return (
    <div style={folderImage}>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't think it's wrong to do it your way either, but I haven't seen it around much. If you're more comfortable with your way of using functions for styling, then try it for a while and see if you like it.

I usually use functions for functionality and data handling and objects for styling. It's just easier to separate between the two once you're working on larger projects.

PS. On line 4 of your code you're checking with !! - Don't do that.

Comment: You are creating the object in the render function. If you do that, React will unnecessarily re-render every time because it will always see it as a new object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have done is fine and is ok to do according to me. But, I would do something like this.

```
<div className="some-class-name" style={!!this.state.folder.image? {backgroundImage: this.state.folder.image} : {}}>
```

"some-class-name" name will have css properties. Now, only if !!this.state.folder.image condition matches you can override those properties which are absolutely necessary with inline style.

Comment: The problem is you shouldn't create new objects in the render for performance reasons. See the articles I linked in my answer for reasons.